# C++program that calculates the volume of a cone

Tags: c++

I don't have trouble compiling this code but it doesn't run properly. Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    float height;
    float radius;
    float volume;

    volume=.3333333333333333333333333333333*radius*radius*height;


    cout<<"Enter height:"<<endl;
    cin>>height;
    cout<<"Enter radius:"<<endl;
    cin>>radius;

    if(height==0&&radius==0){
        cout<<"Not a valid solution";

    }

    if(height==0&&radius!=0){
        cout<<"not a valid a solution"<<endl;


    }

    if(height!=0&&radius==0){

        cout<<"not a valid solution"<<endl;
    }

    if(height<0&&radius<0){

        cout<<"Not a valid solution";
    }

    if(height<0&&radius>0){

        cout<<"Not a valid solution";
    }

    if(height>0&&radius<0){

        cout<<"Not a valid solution";
    }
    if(height>0&&radius>0){
        cout<<"Volume is "<<volume<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it and it asks me to input the values for radius and height, the volume is always zero: Here is what I mean:

```
Enter height:
9.0
Enter radius:
9.0
Volume is 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calculating volume before you enter the the height and radius.

Comment: FYI: the code is executed sequentially...

Answer (score 5):

C++ is a sequential programming language, not a declarative one. Statements are generally executed from top to bottom (with the exception of jump instructions like function calls, goto, and loops). So when you do this:

```
volume=.3333333333333333333333333333333*radius*radius*height;
```

The calculation uses the current values of `radius` and `height` (which are both uninitialized at the time this statement is executed). The value of `volume` is not updated when `radius` and `height` change later on. Put that statement *after* you have the user inputted values.

If you want the value of `volume` to update automatically with `height` and `radius`, you could make it a lambda:

```
auto volume = [&radius,&height]() {
    return .3333333333333333333333333333333*radius*radius*height;
};

cin >> radius >> height;
cout << volume() << '\n';
```

By the way, you have a lot of redundant checks. All your `if` statements can be reduced to this:

```
if (height <= 0 || radius <= 0) {
    // not a valid solution
}
else {
    // calculate and print solution
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you are setting the volume before you even give height and radius anything, try moving it below the cin and then come back if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You are computing `volume` before accepting user input. Move the line

```
volume=.3333333333333333333333333333333*radius*radius*height;
```

to after

```
cin>>radius;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line has already been calculated at compile time:

```
volume=.3333333333333333333333333333333*radius*radius*height;
```

Your best bet would be to create a function and call it after the user has finished inputting the radius and height:

```
float calculate_volume(float r, float h)
{
    return .3333333333333333333333333333333*r*r*h;
}

if(height>0&&radius>0){
    cout<<"Volume is "<< calculate_volume(radius, height) <<endl;

}
```